# detect submit event on custom form control in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a custom form control on which i must implement updateOn all 3 of available options 'change | submit | blur'. i have succeeded in both change and blur but how can i determine when the parent formGroup was submitted? i know that  formGroupDirective have submitted prop but in my case it always stays false.

to get access to formGroupDirective inside custom component i did the following:

`constructor(@Self() private injector: Injector)`

and in ngOnInit ->

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.control = this.injector.get(NgControl);
    this.form = this.control._parent; -> this will have ref to parent formGroupDirective of the control as i understand
    console.log(this.form);
}
```

the formGroupDirective also have ngSubmit eventEmitter but it wont fire on submittion.

how can i make it work. please Advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject in your constructor the FormGroupDirective

```
get isSubmited()
{
   return this.formDirective?this.formDirective.submitted:false;
}
constructor(@Optional() private formDirective:FormGroupDirective){
   this.form=this.formDirective?formDirective.form:null //<--better that access to parent
  
}
```

I used `@Optional` in case your component has no parent don't give an error

**Update** I don't know if it's a great idea, but we can use the getter to know when change.

Imagine declare a variable _isSubmited

```
_isSubmitted=false;
get isSubmited()
{
   const submited=this.formDirective?this.formDirective.submitted:false;
   if (this._isSubmited!=submited)
   {
      this._isSubmited=submited
      ..and make something more...
   }

   return this._isSubmited
}
```

But you need in .html use isSubmitted, If you don't use, you always can create a fool div

```
<div style="visibility:hidden">{{isSubmited}}</div>
```

Comment: Hi Eliseo thanks for your answer. I need this submitted flag to reflect it changes on the fly so i need some sort of Observable to subscribe to it. i've tried to subscribe to formDirective.statusChange but the flag on submition still stays flase.

Comment: @Alex, statusChange only applied to VALID,INVALID,PENDING or DISABLE, so you can create a fool asyncValidator. I don't know if it's a good idea use the getter -see the updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your help. found the bug it was that (ngSubmit) event was on the form and also on the submit button. when i removed it from the button it works like a charm :-)